# ios azure pipeline build fails with build with error no team ID found in the archive

Tags: ios, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

I am using azure pipeline to create CI for iOS and my repository  depend on swift code and after running the build I got this error in the Xcode archive task

```
Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}
```

I am using arg in the Xcode archive tasks

```
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode archive'
  inputs:
    actions: archive
    xcWorkspacePath: '*.xcworkspace'
    scheme: '$(SchemeName)'
    packageApp: true
    args: '-UseModernBuildSystem=0  '
```

Comment: If you want to create an archive then you will need to supply a provisioning profile and possibly a signing identity.

Comment: I try to supply  provisioning profile and possibly a signing identity but it is the same

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question to show more content of your yaml file.  You will need to upload a provisioning profile as a secure file and use a `InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1` to make it available to your pipeline.

Comment: Okay I will now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to set the `exportOptions` to specify and set the attributes `teamId` and `exportMethod` for Xcode task. See below example:

```
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode archive'
  inputs:
    actions: archive
    xcWorkspacePath: '*.xcworkspace'
    scheme: '$(SchemeName)'
    packageApp: true
    args: '-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
    exportOptions: 'specify'
    exportMethod: 'app-store'
    teamId: "Team Id" 
    exportTeamId: "Team Id"
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) for more information about xcode task.

Answer (score 1):

**Install certificates and provisioning profile**

To sign your application you will need to install the certificate and provisioning profile that we have already imported into the Azure dashboard as a [Secure-Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    # Select the certificate (.p12) that was uploaded to Secure Files to install on the macOS agent.
    certSecureFile: 'Certificate.p12' 
    # Password to the Apple certificate (.p12). Use a new build variable with its lock enabled on the Variables tab to encrypt this value.
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    # Select the keychain in which to install the Apple certificate. You can choose to install the certificate in a temporary keychain (default), the default keychain or a custom keychain. A temporary keychain will always be deleted after the build or release is complete.
    keychain: 'temp'
    # Select to delete the certificate from the keychain after the build or release is complete. This option is visible when custom keychain or default keychain are selected.
    deleteCert: true

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
  # Select the location of the provisioning profile to install. The provisioning profile can be uploaded to Secure Files or stored in your source repository or a local path on the agent.
    provProfileSecureFile: 'my-provisioning-profile.mobileprovision'
```

Comment: can you please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73540723/how-to-update-xcode-version-to-13-4-1-in-azure-pipeline this error