# How to update XCODE version to 13.4.1 in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: xcode, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, testflight

I am deploying application using azure pipeline getting below error

```
module compiled with Swift 5.6.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.
```

I have tried changing configurations but no luck, any help will be thankful

> Locale machine File and configurations

- MacOS 12.5.1
- Xcode version is 13.4.1

> Azure executing below version of xcode

- Xcode 13.2.1

> .yml file

```
trigger:
- main

  pool:
   vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

  variables:
  - group: App Variables

 steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.19.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: yarn install
  displayName: Install Dependencies

- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
      workingDirectory: ios
      forceRepoUpdate: false
      displayName: 'Install CocoaPods dependencies'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: 'Release'
      sdk: 'iphoneos15.2'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/EsApp.xcworkspace'
      scheme: 'EsApp'
      packageApp: true
      archivePath: 'output/archive'
      exportPath: 'output/package'
      exportOptions: plist
      exportOptionsPlist: 'ios/ExportOptions.plist'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, this problem is related to the XCODE version of the Microsoft-hosted agent, in the "macOS-latest" is using the "macOS 11 Big Sur" image, and it supports the highest XCODE version is 13.2.1.

You could use the "macOS-12" Microsoft-hosted agent to use the XCODE 13.4.1.

If you are mentioning `SDK` then use `SDK "iphoneos15.5"`

```
  pool:
   vmImage: 'macOS-12'
```

For more information about software of Microsoft-hosted agent, you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Comment: Now `vmImage: 'macOS-12` targetting to `Xcode 14.0.1` how can set to specific `13.4.1`

Comment: Use xcodeVersion in XCode@5 task.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops